# MomentJS Converting EPOC millisecond to date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I receive two types of date, seconds and milliseconds for which i am trying to convert to a date.

```
Seconds:      1458820878062
Milliseconds: 1458823059491000
```

I can convert seconds via:

```
function convertToDate() {

    var date = 1458820878062;

    var m = moment.utc(date).utcOffset(moment().format('ZZ'));

    return m.format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSS');

}
```

How can i convert milliseconds in to a date? And apply the necessary conversion to whatever date may be?

Something along the lines of:

```
if(date.length = 13) {
   // Do seconds conversion
if(date.length > 13) {
   // Do milliseconds conversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
moment("/Date(1458823059491000/1000)/")
```

ie., you need to divide the milliseconds by 1000 to get the time in seconds and then you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, how can i check length of date.. have tried: if(date.toString().length = 13) { but get error TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of string

Comment: @OamPsy:- `check length of date`...what you wanna do with that?

Comment: Because some times are in seconds. If i apply /1000 to a second format it would become 145882087.8062 hence i only want to /1000 when in millisecond.

Comment: @OamPsy:- Then you need to check at the source itself(*in my opinion that would be a good idea*), i.e., you need to make sure that you are passing only seconds or milliseconds to your function as input parameter and then handle it accordingly, so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: The date syntax is unnecessary - moment added it as an adaptation for ASP.NET versions that send that in JSON objects. Moment accepts plain integer values for timestamps. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Moment supports both operations out of the box.

If you have seconds, use moment.unix:

```
moment.unix(1458855925).format()
"2016-03-24T16:45:25-05:00"
```

If you have milliseconds, just use the moment constructor directly:

```
moment(1458856019742).format()
"2016-03-24T16:46:59-05:00"
```

To get the unix seconds from a moment, use:

```
moment().unix()
1458856086
```

To get the unix milliseconds from a moment, use:

```
moment().valueOf()
1458856019742
```

Answer (score -1):

How about just check `if(data > 1e13)` ?